# how to select parent item with scss

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul id="navbar-main" class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <a href="https://travian.dev/materials" class="nav-link nav-materials">
            <span class="invisible">Materials</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the following SCSS:

```
#navbar-main {
  li {
    &.nav-item {
      .nav-link {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background: no-repeat center;
        background-size: contain;

        &.nav-materials {
          background-image: url('../images/buttons/menu-materials.png');
        }
      }

      &.active {
        .nav-link {
          &.nav-materials {
            background: red;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is working, but I'd like it more maintainable/ easier to read. If possible, I'd like it to be like this:

```
#navbar-main {
  li {
    &.nav-item {
      .nav-link {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background: no-repeat center;
        background-size: contain;

        &.nav-materials {
          background-image: url('../images/buttons/menu-materials.png');

          .active { // here something to actually select .nav-item.active .navlink.nav-materials
            background: red;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't, because `.active` is a class on the `<li>` element. You can't traverse upwards with your selectors.

Comment: IMHO this question is about the Sass parent selector `&` (and `@at-root` and `#{&}`) which, well, exists and not the CSS parent selector (this queston was closed as a dupe and reopened)

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't think you can really improve on the original SCSS you offered. The Sass parent selector (`&`) selects the *entire chain* of parents.

It's rather awkward, but you could use `@at-root` to return to the root of your style sheet, and then replace part of your selector, like so:

```scss
/// Replace `$search` with `$replace` in `$string`
/// @author Hugo Giraudel
/// @param {String} $string - Initial string
/// @param {String} $search - Substring to replace
/// @param {String} $replace ('') - New value
/// @return {String} - Updated string
@function str-replace($string, $search, $replace: '') {
  $index: str-index($string, $search);
  
  @if $index {
    @return str-slice($string, 1, $index - 1) + $replace + str-replace(str-slice($string, $index + str-length($search)), $search, $replace);
  }
  
  @return $string;
}

#navbar-main {
  li {
    &.nav-item {
      .nav-link {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background: no-repeat center;
        background-size: contain;

        &.nav-materials {
          background-image: url('../images/buttons/menu-materials.png');

          @at-root #{str-replace(#{&}, ".nav-item", ".nav-item.active")} {
            background: red;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think it is possible to *insert* part of a selector in-between the parent selector in Scss **in a maintainable way** but maybe…

First, useful documentation: [the Sass Ampersand (and the 3 articles at the end!)](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/) from CSS-Tricks references [using a mixin](https://gist.github.com/jayroh/1052807#file-quicksand-mixin-css) after the well known cases where `&` can be used (and where it can't) and also `#{&}` when you want to use `&` twice (I didn't know about the latter and I tried+failed many times with `&&` and `li&`, *sigh*).

[This mixin](https://gist.github.com/jayroh/1052807#file-quicksand-mixin-css) *as is* wouldn't help in your case but here's my take:

**Scss mixin** that'll take 3 parameters to build one or another selector and any block of rule

➡️ **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/YvPpNP?editors=0100)**

```css
@mixin nav-bg($parent, $active, $sel) {
  @at-root #{$parent} {
    &#{$active $sel} {
      @content;
    }
  }
}


#navbar-main {
  li {
    &.nav-item {
      .nav-link {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background: no-repeat center;
        background-size: contain;
      }

      @include nav-bg(&, '', '.nav-materials') {
        background-image: url('../images/buttons/menu-materials.png');
      }

      @include nav-bg(&, '.active', '.nav-materials') {
        background: red;
      }
    }
  }
}


// output
#navbar-main li.nav-item .nav-link {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
}
#navbar-main li.nav-item .nav-materials {
  background-image: url("../images/buttons/menu-materials.png");
}
#navbar-main li.nav-item.active .nav-materials {
  background: red;
}
```

---

If your goal is to be as **maintainable** as possible, I'd advise you to completely change your way of nesting selectors and **reduce their specificity**.
Here's how I'd rewrite your block:

➡️ **[Less specificity (Codepen)](https://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/rKaMMm?editors=0100)**

```css
#navbar-main {
  .nav-link {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: no-repeat center;
    background-size: contain;
  }

  .nav-materials {
    background-image: url('../images/buttons/menu-materials.png');
  }

  .active {
    .nav-materials {
      background: red;
    }
  }
}

Sass references: [@content](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixin-content), [@at-root](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#at-root)
```

I'd also replace that id by a class, even for components that you know for sure will only exist once on a page. I resisted for a couple of years in that case and it's nearly as much a plague than i other cases…

[Keep your CSS selectors short](https://csswizardry.com/2012/05/keep-your-css-selectors-short/) by CSSWizardry is a good start (scan his archives from 2012 to 2016 for way more)
CSS methodologies *that scale©*: